# tmux does not inherit $SHELL variable from shell launching tmux

Tags: shell, environment-variables, tmux

After updating my `/etc/shell` file and typing a `csh -s /usr/local/bin/zsh` afterwards, I decided to quit and relaunch tmux with hope it will take account of my new $SHELL environment variable. Unfortunately, tmux still shows the old `/bin/zsh` after typing `echo $SHELL`.

How to tell tmux to inherit the $SHELL variable of the shell that launched it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set-option -g default-shell "$SHELL_PATH"
```

in ~/.tmux.conf or /etc/tmux.conf. Works on arch.

You can reload the config file with : source-file  e.g.

```
<C-b>: source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

You would need to do it for every tmux instance. Otherwise you may restart

```
tmux with killall tmux; tmux
```

these commands will change the path of shell in tmux